# Remove [] brackets while sending response in Salesforce

Tags: rest-api, wsdl

I have a class which sends the response for a request received. I have pasted the response below. I want to remove the [] brackets in the starting and the ending of the response.

[{
"Status": "Success",
"Message": "Booking Update received"
}]

Request for a suggestion to remove the brackets.

Comment: Is this a custom response created by yourself

Comment: That appears to be [JSON](https://www.json.org/) which is generally a good format to send structured data in. It is an array of objects, so if there is only ever one object you could just serialize that not the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This string method removes the first and last char of a string. Use this string method to remove the brackets.

```
yourstringName.substring(1,yourstringName.length()-1);
```

Comment: brilliant help...thnx everyone